# Doubts about this liquidity pair

Tags: liquiditypool

I have been studying for a couple of days how transactions are executed in the Solana network to know how each one of them works, I have come across a couple of cases that I still cannot decipher, this one for example.https://solscan.io/account/wifq4CRwpXCK8NYtKNsQAYoDethT1aR7R1DaKCLFgAd

I understand according to the raydium documents that to create a liquidity pair for a spl token to be tradable it is necessary to create a market id, therefore pay something like 3 SOL of fees, now my question is, how do I create this dev your liquidity pair?, skipping this payment

Comment: the link you provided isn't a transaction link

Comment: greetings friends ....correct, the link you provide is from the developer's wallet, what I can't describe is how the step of creating a market id was skipped, to be able to add lp in raydium

Comment: Can you add some more details about the additional required fees? Typically, you need to pay some amount of fees to cover the rent-exempt reserve in an account with allocated bytes, but the example you gave is just a normal wallet, which is strange.

Comment: greetings friend, normally to add a pair of lp in raydium it is necessary to pay a fee of 3 Sol, since it is necessary to create a market id, according to your documents, my main doubt is that I have seen many developers add lp in raydium skipping this 3 soles fee to create the market id, As you can see, the dev in the transaction link does not pay those 3 Sol fees at any time, and still manages to create a pair of LPs in Raydium, how does he do it?